# Can't change color of text inside animated button

Tags: html, css

Just doing a project for school, and I used a style found on w3 schools for an animated button. For whatever reason, I can't seem to change the color of the text inside the button. I am fairly new to HTML, so if you notice what I'm doing wrong and can give a short explanation it would be greatly appreciated! I apologize if this has been asked already or if this is remedial stuff.

```css
.button {
  float: center;
  display: flex;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #a6a6a6;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 26px;
  padding: 20px;
  min-width: 15.96%;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.button span:after {
  content: '»';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}
.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle">
  <a href="first.html"><span>Home</span></button></a>
<button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle">
  <a href="index.html"><span>About me</span></button></a>
<button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle">
  <a href="contact.html"><span>Contact</span></button></a>
<button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle">
  <a href="projects.html"><span>Projects</span></button></a>
<button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle">
  <a href="resume.html"><span>Resume</span></button></a>
<button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle">
  <a href="other.html"><span>Other</span></button></a>
```

Comment: Couple of questions: Why do you give the `<button>` a class of 'button'? you can just style and refer to those elements as `button`. Secondly.. why does the button have a `<a>` tag in it? Thats semantically incorrect. You also got a stray `<div>` tag and you closed the `<buttons>` and `<a>` the wrong way around.

Comment: I am very new to html, I didn't know that I didn't need the <button> class. By your second part, do you mean that I can just use href?

Comment: I'd do it the other way around. Use the `<a>` tag instead of the `<button>`. Buttons are for forms, anchor (`<a>`) tags are for redirecting users to another page / part of a page.

Comment: Thank you @putvande, I think I get it now, and that definitely worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need a button **and** an anchor tag. that's redundant, just add the button class to your anchor tag like so..

```
<a class="button" href="first.html" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>Home</span></a>
```

repeat for the other buttons.

Comment: :DD Haha thanks again man, I am sure a lot of this is remedial but I'm glad you showed me the correct way of doing it. All of the answers were extremely appreciated, but I'm glad you pointed out the redundancy of what I showed.

Answer (score 0):

These `<a>` links override the color you're setting. Recolor the links themselves:

```
.button a{
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

You've also closed the `<a>` tags after buttons, but should've done that before the buttons, otherwise you get wrong hierarchy.

---

Demo:

```css
.button a{
   color: #FFFFFF; 
}
.button {
  float: center;
  display: flex;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #a6a6a6;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 26px;
  padding: 20px;
  min-width: 15.96%;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  
}

.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.button span:after {
  content: '»';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}
.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>About me</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle"><a href="first.html"><span>Home</span></a></button>
    <button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle"><a href="index.html"><span>About me</span></a></button>
    <button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle"><a href="contact.html"><span>Contact</span></a></button>
    <button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle"><a href="projects.html"><span>Projects</span></a></button>
    <button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle"><a href="resume.html"><span>Resume</span></a></button>
    <button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle"><a href="other.html"><span>Other</span></a></button>

    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ahhhh, I get it now. Thank you very much for the information. Someone stated above, that <a> inside the button is incorrect, is that bad practice to do that?

Comment: @Wardy It's not a bad practice, it's just wrong. You should keep the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

One Your HTML tags are off -- Not nested correctly .. Use this .. The `<a>` tags are nested correctly in the following code:

```
<button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle"><a href="first.html"><span>Home</span></a></button>
<button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle"><a href="index.html"><span>About me</span></a></button>
<button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle"><a href="contact.html"><span>Contact</span></a></button>
<button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle"><a href="projects.html"><span>Projects</span></a></button>
<button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle"><a href="resume.html"><span>Resume</span></a></button>
<button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle"><a href="other.html"><span>Other</span></a></button>
```

Then you can use this to color it correctly:

```
.button a span{
  color:#FFF;
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/6jrj6f9u/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try by changing the button span part???

Replace this

```
.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

by this

```
.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: red; /* or whatever you like */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close, but here's the sample code:

```
<button class="button"><a href="first.html"><span>Home</span></a></button>
<button class="button"><a href="index.html"><span>About me</span></a></button>
<button class="button"><a href="contact.html"><span>Contact</span></a></button>
<button class="button"><a href="projects.html"><span>Projects</span></a></button>
<button class="button"><a href="resume.html"><span>Resume</span></a></button>
<button class="button"><a href="other.html"><span>Othe</span></a></button>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.button {
  float: center;
  display: flex;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #a6a6a6;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 26px;
  padding: 20px;
  min-width: 15.96%;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.button span:after {
  content: '»';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
```

Also, here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/UXEngineer/0847o2ym/1/